# vue.js not work as expected

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to use vue.js in the following example, but the result in browser is ["product"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MltWi.png) instead of "Boots".

```html
<div id="app">
    <h2>{{product}}</h2>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js">
    const app = new vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
    product: "Boots"
    }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: vue must be capital. so change it to `app = new Vue({`

Comment: Also, don't put your script code inside the same `<script>` that's getting Vue. Make a new `script` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `vue` to `Vue`, then works.

```js
app = new Vue({ //not vue, it is Vue
    el: "#app",
    data: {
    product: "Boots"
    }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <h2>{{product}}</h2>
</div>
```